# unable to login wordpress localhost xaamp

Tags: wordpress, localhost

I am getting an error whenever i try to open `http://localhost/wordpress/wp-admin/`

> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function mysql_connect() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php:1668 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php(632): wpdb->db_connect() #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\load.php(425): wpdb->__construct('root', '', 'practice_debut', 'localhost') #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-settings.php(116): require_wp_db() #3 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-config.php(90): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #4 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-load.php(37): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #5 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-blog-header.php(13): require_once('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #6 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\index.php(17): require('C:\xampp\htdocs...') #7 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\wp-db.php on line 1668
>
> Fatal error: Uncaught Error: Call to undefined function wp_kses_normalize_entities() in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\formatting.php:4316 Stack trace: #0 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(190): esc_url('https://wordpre...') #1 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(147): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_default_error_template(Array, false) #2 C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\class-wp-fatal-error-handler.php(52): WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->display_error_template(Array, false) #3 [internal function]: WP_Fatal_Error_Handler->handle() #4 {main} thrown in C:\xampp\htdocs\wordpress\wp-includes\formatting.php on line 4316

when  i tried for solutions i came across this one "untick mysqli and tick nd_mysqli"
but i don't know how to do this in localhost xamamp. I am new to wordpress and localhost.

Also when i tried to open `http://localhost/phpmyadmin/`
i get this error

> phpMyAdmin - Error
>   The mysqli extension is missing. Please check your PHP configuration. See [a@doc/html/faq.html#faqmysql@documentation]our documentation for more information.

Comment: Please make sure the extension=mysqli.dll isn't commented out into php.ini.

Also, make sure that you have the mysqli.dll files that exist inside the extensions folder of your PHP installation.

Comment: exactly same settings

Comment: follow this steps and check if it is working
in file php.ini this line: extension=mysqli.dll

Replace by: extension="C:\php\ext\php_mysqli.dll"

Restart apache

Comment: already done that but not working in my case

Answer (score -1):

Try to use Wampserver64 application. Maybe your problem solved.